# Why study solvability of polynomials of prime degree?

Tags: galois-theory

Galois investigated the solvability by radicals of polynomials of prime and prime-squared degree. These results are presented in modern form in chapter 15 of Cox's book on Galois Theory. Here is an example of a result of this type:

> Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial of prime degree over a field $K$ of characteristic zero. Then $f$ is solvable by radicals iff, for any two roots $a, b$ of $f$, $K(a, b)$ is a splitting field of $f$.

Why study the solvability of polynomials of specifically prime degree? Can the general case be reduced to this case? In number theory we often study the prime/prime-power case rather than the general case because the Chinese Remainder Theorem allows us to reduce the latter to the former, but that doesn't seem likely here because $\deg fg=\deg f + \deg g$ and not $\deg fg = \deg f \deg g$, so I can't see how primeness of degree could be relevant.

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps it has something to do with Galois groups of the extensions. Groups of order $p$ and $p^2$ are always commutative.

Comment: If you read Galois' original writings, he didn't talk in terms of groups, they were there lurking under the surface but he worked in a much more concrete manner.  So for example instead of saying something was a "normal" subgroup, he just stuck to the case where things are commutative or close to it, as we now call it.  Things of prime order are just simpler, and this is what he realized in a very concrete way.  You should read Edwards' Galois Theory book where he actually takes you through Galois' original proof.

Comment: It's very enlightening and shows you how Galois did it in a way you can understand.  In other words you see him as a mortal genius after reading this, instead of a creepy god-like figure which is how many of us think of him, given the treatment of the subject as we learn it now and being told it was developed by a 19 year old.  In reality it was fairly down-to-earth as he formulated it.  The abstract version came slowly over the next 80 years.

Answer (score 0):

I dare say that in this context a key connection is that the maximal transitive solvable subgroups of $S_p$ are contained in a conjugate of the holomorph $C_p\rtimes C_{p-1}$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28956/11619) for the oldest (AFAICT) appearance of this group theoretic result on our site. If you know that
$K(a,b)/K$ is Galois, then so is $K(a,b)/K(a)$. As a subgroup of $S_p$ the latter is a point-stabilizer of one of the roots.

For non-prime $n$ probably quite a bit is known about maximal transitive solvable subgroups of $S_n$, but I'm too ignorant to say more about that.

Comment: Not really an answer along the lines of Jack M's question, but I think this does explain why the case of prime degree polynomials is simpler.